# TF2 - Splitting Input Data & Using Different Pre-Trained Weights of a Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have individually trained the same neural network architecture on a large number of different datasets (order of 100s) to learn a unique non-linear function for each i.e have basically learned a set of weights that describes the function for each dataset.

Now, I want to use these sets of weights as a pre-trained layer in another optimization problem. I know how to load in a single saved model and employ that as a layer. However, what I will be doing is a group-wise optimization across the 100s of different datasets, where I have a pre-trained weights for each (from above).

So the setup is a batch of x datasets, each with n data points in d dimensions i.e. input data is of the shape [X, N, D]. There are a series of layers which act on all this data, then when it gets to the "pre-trained" layer, I wish to use different pre-trained weights i.e. For [0,:,:] uses the weights learned from dataset 0 from above, [1,:,:] with weights learned from dataset 1 etc etc etc.

I then need to combine the output of all this together, as the loss function for this groupwise optimization is based on the variance across all datasets. So I don't believe I can trivially evaulate one set, calculate loss, change weights, rinse and repeat and sum up at the end.

I doubt it is feasible to have some massive duplicate branches going, where I have x copies of the pre-trained NN layers as the pre-trained NN architecture is already quite complex.

Is it is possible to use a split layer, then a for loop type approach, in which I change the weights, then pass the correct portion of data through? Then merge all the outputs? Or is there a better way of tackling this?

Any help much appreciated.